# UIImageView Define Size without .frame

Tags: ios6, iphone-5, xcode4.5

I have a UIScrollView with paging enabled. I want to full it with images and I have a UIImageView which needs to be made to fit without using `.frame`. This is because it doesn't work with Autolayout enabled. Not using Autolayout isn't an option.

Here's the code as it stands:

```
//Prepare and load the view
[scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), (kScrollObjHeight))];
scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;
[scrollView1 setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

CGRect Rect = scrollView1.bounds;
UIImageView *beadContainer;

for (int i = 0; i < imageViews.count; i++)
{
    beadContainer = [imageViews objectAtIndex:i];
    beadContainer.frame = Rect;
    [scrollView1 addSubview:beadContainer];
    Rect.origin.x += Rect.size.width;
}
```

None of the images appear as it stands, though the ScrollView has all of the right dimensions and scrolls as expected. If I comment out `beadContainer.frame = Rect;`, then all of the images in the array `imageViews` appear at `0, 0`. They all show up on top of one another. Of course, I need them to fill the ScrollView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use autolayout to layout the images?

```
//Prepare and load the view
[scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), (kScrollObjHeight))];
scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;
[scrollView1 setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];



UIImageView *firstImage = imageViews[0];
UIImageView *lastImageView = [imageViews lastObject];
UIImageView *previousImageView = nil;
NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray new];
for (UIImageView *imageView in imageViews){
    [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];
    //set the size of the images
    [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:nil
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                       multiplier:1.0f
                                                         constant:kScrollObjWidth]];
    [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:nil
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                       multiplier:1.0f
                                                         constant:kScrollObjHeight]];
    //remove autoresizing masks
    [imageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    //pin the top of the imageview to the top of the superview
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageView]"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView)]];

    if ([firstImage isEqual:imageView]){ //pin the first image view to the left of the scrollview
        [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithVisualFormat:@"|[firstImage]"
                                                                                options:0
                                                                                metrics:nil
                                                                                  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(firstImage)]];
    }

    if (previousImageView){ //pin any imageViews to the previous imageViews
        [constraints addObjectFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithVisualFormat:@"[previousImageView][imageView]"
                                                                               options:0
                                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                                 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView, previousImageView)]];
    }
    previousImageView = imageView;
}

[scrollView1 addConstraints:constraints];
```

Mind you I haven't tried this, it might be rubbish code, I wrote it in a text editor.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for writing this up. I'll tinker with it and see if it gets the job done. Thought constraints and autolayout were supposed to make my life easier, but this has been no cake walk. Thanks again and I'll report back!

Comment: The code might be long, but they're actually easier to read and understand compared to setting frames via math. Especially, but doesn't seem in your case, that you set some padding between each of the views, all the little things add up to a messy conglomerate. The code for adding spaces isn't much different from the code above, just change the [previousImageView][imageView] to [previousImageView]-[imageView]

Comment: After going over this it makes a LOT more sense. You're right. Far more readable. There is one issue, though. After ironing out some of the kinks, I can no longer interact with the images. Do you have any ideas about why that might be? I'll continue working on it and will report if I fix it.

Comment: From what I can tell, it seems like `scrollView1` is not actually receiving swipe motions or progressing. Could this be in some way due to `imageView in imageViews`?

Comment: Shouldn't be due to the for statement block, check your scroll view's content size.

Comment: Also, if you're detecting taps in a uiageview you have to setUserInteractionEnabled on each uiimageview.

Comment: So strange. User interaction is enabled across the board. I even set it for every view related to that section to be sure. scrollView1 is the scroll view and it's size is set by the three variables at the very beginning of the code above. Still looking into it, but I'm kind of at a loss...

Perhaps of note, I have a reset button that scrolls back to (0, 0). I changed it to scroll elsewhere in the view and it too seems to have no effect. Time to start looking for superfluous brackets, I guess.

Comment: `imageViews` is an NSArray, if that changes anything. That's what I'm currently tinkering with.

Comment: ANSWER TO PROBLEM: Anyone who reads this, the issue is that the code does not define where the then last image belongs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use auto layout fully, do NOT set the scroll view's `contentSize`. Just lay out the contents fully with constraints, making sure to describe the size of every one of the contents subviews, and the distance of the contents subviews from the bounds of an imaginary rectangle surrounding them. The runtime will automagically use that imaginary rectangle to create the content size.